# Custom lead conversion process with custom lead mapping

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, metadata-api, lead-conversion

I want to create the custom lead conversion process where user can map the standard fields as well with the objects(Account, Contact, Opportunity) fields. In short I want to override the standard lead conversion process of salesforce along with standard lead mapping functionality.

I have created the LWC component for the same where the user can map the fields. Once after mapping I'm creating the records in the custom object named **Lead_Mapping__c**. Now how can i achieve the further functionality so that whatever the field mapping is selected in the page should be applied at the time of conversion? Can someone please help?

**PS: Hospital** is my standard object **Account**

Below are the screenshots for the page that I have created:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you will need to write a trigger on Lead. I would probably go for an `after update` and do something like this:

I would first create a map of all Account/Contact/Opportunity ids as a key and a set of lead ids as their value(in case multiple leads can be converted into the same accounts/contacts/opportunities).
Then, I would query these objects and loop through the lead mapping and the objects to find matches. Once a match is found, I would use the standard `Sobject` object `get()` and `put()` methods to fill in the fields.

Example:

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> accToLeadMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
if (newLead.isConverted && !oldLead.isConverted) {
    if (!accToLeadMap.containsKey(newLead.ConvertedAccountId)) {
        accToLeadMap.put(newLead.ConvertedAccountId, new Set<Id>());
    }
    accToLeadMap.get(newLead.ConvertedAccountId).add(newLead.Id);
}
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accToLeadMap.keySet()];
for (Lead_Mapping__c lm : yourLeadMappings) {
    for (Account a : accs) {
        if (lm.Mapping_Object__c == 'Account') {
            for (Id leadId : accToLeadMap.get(a.Id)) {
                a.put(lm.Mapping_Field__c, newLeadMap.get(leadId).get(lm.Lead_Field__c));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code I provided shows only Account as example, you can make it more generic by using `Sobject` instead

Comment: Hello @Novarg, thank you for the solution, can you please specify what's this newLead and oldLead here? Is this a list of lead as Trigger.New and Trigger.Old?

Comment: @AdityaDeshmukh newLead and oldLead are instances of a separate lead record before and after save. It's to make sure that we only process leads that were just converted and ignore the ones that were converted long time ago

Comment: Thanks, just the last doubt, what's the yourLeadMappings in for loop and newLeadMap in the last line because they are not defined?

Comment: @AdityaDeshmukh that's literally your custom object. Make sure you query it before. And newLeadMap is Trigger.newMap